# Solve this initial value problem $y'=\tan^2(5x+5y)$, with the initial condition $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: The full info is in this image]

So I'm about to lose my hair, I already have 60 attempts done for this problem.

I took $u= 5x+5y$, which gave me $u'= 5+5y'$.

Then I isolated $y'= (u'-5)/5$, which would give me

$5\tan^2(u)+5 = u'$ and then I have integral of $dx = \int \frac{du}{5\tan^2(u)+5}$.

And after by using an integral calculator I get that $x +C= \frac{\tan(u)}{10\tan^2(u) +10} +\frac u{10}$.

By replacing the $u$ back and using the initial condition $y(0)=0$, I get $C=0$ and the solution that I found was $\frac{\tan(5(x+y))}{10\tan^2(5(x+y) )+10} +\frac{5x+5y}{10} -x$.

Comment: I tried that did not work.

Comment: has you tried the identity $\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}$?

Comment: Its' a duplicate this question has been asked  here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640646/is-somebody-able-to-help-me-with-this/2640662#2640662

Comment: It looks like the other questions are received badly (since that question provides no effort) and could be deleted. You may consider post your answer here. @Isham

Answer (score 2):

Let us observe that
\begin{align}
y' =\tan^2(5x+5y) \ \ \implies&  \ \ \cos^2(5x+5y)y' = \sin^2(5x+5y) = 1-\cos^2(5x+5y)\\
\implies& \ \ \cos^2(5x+5y)(1+y') = 1.
\end{align}
Next, notice if we define $u(x) =5y(x)+5x$, then it follows
\begin{align}
\cos^2(5x+5y)(1+y') = 1 \ \ \implies \ \ \cos^2(u)u' = 5 \ \ \implies \ \ \frac{1+\cos(2u)}{2} du = 5 dx.
\end{align}
Hence the general implicit solution is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}u + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2u)= 5x+C \ \ \implies \ \ \frac{5}{2}(y+x) + \frac{1}{4}\sin(10(x+y))= 5x+C.
\end{align}
Plugging in the initial condition yields
\begin{align}
F(x, y) = \frac{5}{2}(y-x) + \frac{1}{4}\sin(10(x+y))+1 = 1.
\end{align}

**Edit:** The problem looks ill-posed since
\begin{align}
F(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}(y-x) + \frac{1}{20}\sin(10(x+y))+1 = 1.
\end{align}
also works.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\tan^2(5x+5y)$$
Let $u(x)=5x+5y(x)\quad\implies\quad y(x)=\frac15 u(x)-x$
$$y'=\frac15 u'-1=\tan^2(u)\quad\implies\quad \frac15 u'=\frac{1}{\cos^2(u)}$$
This is a separable ODE : $\quad \cos^2(u)du=5dx$

$ \int\cos^2(u)du=\frac14(2u+\sin(2u))=5x+\text{constant} $

$2(5x+5y)+\sin(2(5x+5y))-20x=c$

This is the solution on the form of implicit equation :

$$10(y-x)+\sin(10(x+y))=c$$

The solution cannot be expressed on explicit form $y(x)$ in terms of a finite number of standard functions.

$$ $$